# how to pass revert data in react native without use redux

Tags: react-native

Screen B
const setLocation = () => {navigation.navigate('UserHome', {address: address})}

Screen A
const address = props?.route?.params?.address
console.log('address ===========>', address);

address ===========> undefined

```
const setLocation = () => {
        navigation.navigate('UserHome', {address: address})
    }
```

```
const address = props?.route?.params?.address
  console.log('address ===========>', address);
```

Comment: Can you show the code for screen A please